# How to provide push notification in Oracle Apex 5.1

Tags: oracle-apex-5

Any one help me, how to show the push notification in the navigation bar list, once the record inserted automatically the notification count will increase.

How its possible?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Push notification not have for this time.

i have a option for another way.

1. Create one Application computation in shared component
2. Mention the computation item (Nofify) and select the computation type is sql return single value.
3. wrote your sql query with condition (ex select count(*) cnt from your table)
4. Create the one more list in navigation bar
5. Mention the List Entry Label like ('& nbsp;')
6. Mention your computation item name in User Defined Attributes like &Notify.
7. Save and refresh the page it will show the count